# Insufficient Privileges to debug or run flow

Tags: visual-workflow, permissions

I am trying to debug a specific flow in the flow builder, but every time I do I get the Insufficient Privileges error message. I added the flow to a page in my community and can't see it. However, I have Manage Flows permission, and Run Flows permission. When I try to debug or run other flows I don't have this problem.

Is there a permission that specifically blocks a user from being able to access a specific flow?

The flow is set to run in system mode but so are the others. When I go to the community page as a guest user I can see the flow.

I ran across this article on flow permissions: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_security.htm&type=5

But I cannot find this: "From the Flows Setup page, click Show actions for the flow (Show actions) to edit the access to the specific flow."

Do they mean the specific Flow's Setup page - in which I can't see anything that say show actions or edit access. Or do they mean the Flows Setup page - where there is a different page dealing with the setup of all Flows?

Answer (score 7):

Something I keep forgetting about (and I had this exact problem this morning), is when you are looking at the list of flows, on the right side use the down arrow (carrot?) that allows you to see "View Details and Version" etc. and click on the "Edit Access" and ensure that your profile is granted access to run this flow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also encountering the same error in the flow in production. It's working in UAT. Due to flow access with my profile, you can also grant access by following these steps:

1. Go to Setup and search for 'Flow.'
2. You will find a list of flows. Click on the one for which you want to grant access to the selected profile.
3. Grant access according to your requirements."

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/202533)